# Using user input to set attribute

Tags: python, gpio

*Disclaimer: I have searched for a few days now, without much luck. If, despite that, there is already an answer somewhere, I would appreciate anyone pointing me to it.*

I have been fooling around with RPi.GPIO and python (3.6 at the moment), but hit a minor snag when it comes to setting some attributes. I have been trying to find a way of using user input to set the attributes, along the lines of:

```
mode = input("Enter preferred mode (BCM/BOARD): ").upper()
mode_chosen = "GPIO." + mode
setattr(GPIO, "setmode", mode_chosen)
```

Obviously, the code above sets the attribute to `GPIO.BCM` or `GPIO.BOARD` as strings, which of course doesn't work. I could write an if-else loop that calls `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.whatever)`, depending on the user input, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it.

I am relatively new to python, so chances are I am missing some vital information here, so... thanks in advance to whomever takes the time to answer.

Comment: No need for `setattr` in the last line. As it is written here, it is equivalent to `GPIO.setmode = mode_chosen`, but one of your later comments suggests it should read GPIO.setmoed(mode_chosen)

Comment: You are correct. I am aiming for GPIO.setmode(mode_chosen), the problem is that i do not know how to pass "GPIO.BCM" or "GPIO.BOARD" as an argument, indirectly, without it being a string.

Comment: I find Daniel Roseman's answer helpful.

Comment: Using a dictionary is indeed what I ended up doing. Seems to be the most painless way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a dict:

```
choices = { "BCM": GPIO.BCM, "BOARD": GPIO.BOARD }
mode_chosen = choices[mode]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getattr` to get the attribute from the GPIO module, then use that in `setattr`:

```
mode = input("Enter preferred mode (BCM/BOARD): ").upper()
mode_chosen = getattr(GPIO, mode)
setattr(GPIO, "setmode", mode_chosen)
```

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work.  When trying to setup pins later on, it still gave me: RuntimeError: Please set pin numbering mode using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)